# Needing some visitor-like design pattern

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, design-patterns, mocha.js

I will give you a sample example of my problem to remove the logical complexity and let you be focus on the important part. Of course, this example will be a bit useless...

I have a tree structure where node are like that

```
{
    path: "...",
    childs : []
}
```

Now, I have to write all the full paths from root to each leaf in an array.
My design is very poor:

```
function listPaths(node) {
    var result = [];

    function listForNode(n, parentFullPath) {
        var thisPath = parentFullPath + "/" + n.path;
        result.push(thisPath);
        n.childs.forEach(function (child) {
            listForNode(child, thisPath);
        });
    }

    listForNode(node, "");
    return result;
}
```

It could be nice but I can't write the test with Mocha without having an insane 600 line code test file. At this moment, you should be asking why. The reason is the complexity of the real purpose, that's not relevant for my question. My goal is to having something 'mockable' cause I'm used to. (Java dev). But I fail.

Do you have any pattern that I can use to resolve this one? I'm not really good at JS patterns. :/
Visitor? Making an Y Combinator? So many possibility...

Thank you for reading me

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the "mockable" aspect that you're trying to achieve? I guess I'm trying to understand how that and the 600 line code test file are related. Is it something about the fact that no methods are being called on the JS objects so it's hard to mock the recursive tree visiting function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that functions are first class citizens in javascript.

I see that essentially what you have is something like

```
function createVisitor(parentsAccumulatorInitialValue, parentsAccumulator){

    var visitor = function myVisitor (node) {
        var result;
        function listForNode(n, parentsAcc) {
            var thisPath = parentsAccumulator(parentsAcc, n);
            result.push(thisPath);
            n.childs && n.childs.forEach(function (child) {
                listForNode(child, thisPath);
            });
        }

        result = [];
        listForNode(node, parentsAccumulatorInitialValue());
        return result;
    }
    return visitor;

}

var listPaths = createVisitor(
    function parentInit () {
        return "";
    }, 
    function parentAcc (parentFullPath, n) {
         return parentFullPath + "/" + n.path;        
    });
```

But that's not the only abstraction you could take care of:

```
function createVisitor2(
   totalAccumulatorInitialValue, 
   totalAccumulator, 
   parentsAccumulatorInitialValue, 
   parentsAccumulator){

    var visitor = function myVisitor (node) {
        var total;
        function listForNode(n, parentsAcc) {
            var thisPath = parentsAccumulator(parentsAcc, n);
            total = totalAccumulator(total, thisPath, n);
            n.childs && n.childs.forEach(function (child) {
                listForNode(child, thisPath);
            });
        }

        total = totalAccumulatorInitialValue();
        listForNode(node, parentsAccumulatorInitialValue());
        return total;
    }
    return visitor;

}

var listPaths2 = createVisitor2(
    function totalInit() {
        return [];
    },
    function totalAcc(total, thisPath, n){
        total.push(thisPath);
        return total;
    },
    function parentInit () {
        return "";
    }, 
    function parentAcc (parentFullPath, n) {
         return parentFullPath + "/" + n.path;        
    });
```

Which might be pretty reasonable, but as you can see, I'm already beginning to have trouble finding appropriate names for these variables.   In fact, I'd say the name of our function is bad, as doesn't create anything strictly like a visitor object I know of. However, it does work (BTW, I've slightly modified it to handle nulls as well as empty arrays):

```
> listPaths( { path:"foo", 
             childs: [{path:"bar", childs: null}, {path:"bob", childs: null}]})

["/foo", "/foo/bar", "/foo/bob"]
```

It can be modified even further so that your trees don't strictly even have the same structure... but we're already at 4 parameters, which isn't great.  It'd be better if your visitor creator were passed a single extensible object with all the necessary methods or values.  For instance, maybe (pseudocode):

```
function createVisitor3(opts) {
   //assume we've defined GetDefaults() somewhere local to createVisitor3
   // as well as assume that extend is defined somewhere that copies properties
   // into a new object like various previously existing libraries do.
   opts = extend({}, GetDefaults(), opts);
   var totalAccumulatorInitialValue = opts.totalAccumulatorInitialValue;
   var totalAccumulator = opts.totalAccumulator;
   var parentsAccumulatorInitialValue = opts.parentsAccumulatorInitialValue;
   var parentsAccumulator = opts.parentsAccumulator;
   var childrenGetter = opts.childrenGetter;
   /// etc.
   ...
}
```

Comment: It looks not so simple to me... not so simple as I love to write my code. But I think it's due to the fact I'm just starting JS. It's ok to me, thanks a lot, I will work on that (for 1-2 day I think ^^)

Comment: I confess, there probably is a much simpler to use, more object-oriented pattern based around binary trees that either already exists and can be adapted or can be created, but it'd take me some research to find it (or create it). This gives you a start at least.  I gave you the above code more as an example of how simple it is to take existing code and make it pluggable. However, that, too, can lead to some hard-to-manage code without some forethought. The basis for the methods I've shown you are vaguely based on accumulators in functional programming, which give the developer a lot of power.